# Application tries to randomly connect to the internet. Why?

Tags: c#, .net

I am developing a C# application using .NET Framework 4.0 in VS2010. It is licensed. I have downloaded VS2010 from DreamSpark because I am a student. However, while debugging my application, myapp.vshost.exe tries to connect to various remote IP addresses. Some of them are:

```
194.7.155.82, 199.7.59.190
```

Also, when I compile my app in release mode and use it, my firewall pops-up with my application trying to connect to different IP addresses. My application does not need any internet connection. However, it tries to connect.

**Please advise me on how can I stop this behavior?**

These are the references from my project:

```
Interop.IWshRuntimeLibrary 
Interop.NetFwTypeLib 
System.dll 
System.Management.dll 
System.ServiceModel.dll 
System.ServiceProcess.dll
```

They are all from Microsoft and signed. I don't use any 3rd party libraries.
I have also added this to my app.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <generatePublisherEvidence enabled="false"/>
  </runtime>  
</configuration>
```

Comment: Some information on what your program does would be helpful.

Comment: Also, are you referencing any third-party libraries?

Comment: Also, have you tried creating a brand new, empty console application project to see if it exhibits the same behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're not doing it yourself, it's very likely one of the libraries you're using. Try removing them one by one.

Those are Verisign domains, so it's also possible that some signatures are being checked.

Answer (score 6):

The first of those is owned by Cybertrust, and the second is owned by Thawte. Both of them seem to contain CRL (Certificate Revocation List) files. So my guess is that you're using a library which uses certificates, and a library is checked to see if they're revoked.

It's hard to say any more without knowing anything about what libraries you're using or what the app's doing.

Comment: If I don't use any external libraries, but only the ones from above, who tries to connect ?

Comment: @alexandrud: I couldn't really say offhand, to be honest. Do you do anything which uses HTTPS or some other sort of secure channel?

Comment: I have a GUI executable file and a window service which hosts a WCF service. They communicate through WCF using NetNamedPipeBinding. I only use NET Framework libraries and sometimes I use some interop calls. Nothing fancy.